# ASP.NET MVC & Kendo UI Grid aggregates

Tags: c#, javascript, kendo-ui, aggregates

I am trying to get a sum of all "TransactionAmount"s in the kendo grid I have created.  I have the following code and I am getting a JavaScript error saying the 'sum' is undefined.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<%: Html.Kendo().Grid<Transactions>()
                        .Name("grid_#=AccountNumber#")
                        .Columns(c =>
                        {
                            c.Bound(m => m.TDate).Title("Transaction Date").ClientFooterTemplate("Total:");
                            c.Bound(m => m.TransactionAmount).Title("Transaction Amount").Format("{0:c}").ClientFooterTemplate("#= sum #");
                            c.Bound(m => m.UserName)
                            c.Bound(m => m.Address1)
                            c.Bound(m => m.City)
                            c.Bound(m => m.State)
                        })
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .Aggregates(v => { v.Add(p => p.TransactionAmount).Sum(); })
                            .Read(read => read.Action("GetTransactions", "Reports", new { startDate = Model.StartDate, endDate = Model.EndDate, accountNumber = "#=AccountNumber#" })) 
                        )
                        .Sortable()
                        .ToClientTemplate(#=sum#)  
            %>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.  I noticed a problem with my original question so i edited it to include the correct code.  I'm really a c# developer who was recently thrown into the web world and honestly I'm not exactly sure of the relationships either.  A lot of what I have done is from following examples and copy/paste.  I found this in the kendo demos on telerik's site.  This is the example i'm following:  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: you last line of code `ToClientTemplate(#=sum#)` doesn't look valid